# Should dbnavigator.xml be under gitignore

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have no idea what this file **dbnavigator.xml** is for, but it gets automatically generated every time I open the IntelliJ python project. Should this be under `.gitignore` as well?

The reason why I am not sure is that it is not in the gitignore here at least: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

But since it gets auto generated, I think it is safe to ignore this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is produced by DB Navigator, which is a third-party plugin. It's safe to ignore unless other people working on this project also have the plugin installed and you want to share your database access settings with them.